# Memory management on 500 labels

Tags: objective-c, ios, uilabel

I have a view with several hundred individual `UILabel`s on it. It works, but it is clearly a bog on the system. The app is sluggish until another method releases this view with all the labels.

However, I know that it is necessary often to put this amount of text on a screen, so I'm wondering how is a better way to do it. The labels are each placed in a specific location based on other parameters, so it cannot just be one big textview.

I am guessing the better way to do this is to "draw" the text on the screen using an Open GL Font or something like that. Any other suggestions or advice?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is this view for?

Comment: If you need that much text, try a table view, or a text field?

Comment: Luke, I'm creating dynamic tag clouds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also check Additions to NSString: [NSString UIKit Additions](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html) 
Sample usage:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
        NSString *temperature = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%d / %d", weatherItem.place, high, low];
        [[UIColor blackColor] set];
        [temperature drawInRect:CGRectMake(15.0, 5.0, 50.0, 40.0) withFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:11.0]];
}
```

Comment: hm, this is interesting. this essentially outputs string contents to the screen using Core Graphics rather than UILabel; it should take up less memory then, correct?

Comment: Yes, when using this approach, the string is being rendered on the view and is basically a piece of parent View. So sth like bunch of pixels. If you create UILabel for each string, it is a UIView(check inheritance hierarchy), containing a lot of additional properties

Comment: i'm trying this but my text is apparently being obscured by additional CGContextAddLineToPoint type drawing after the fact; do I draw the strings inside the `CGContextRef context=UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();` or how to draw them separately from the other drawing I'm also doing, so they also show up?

Answer (score 0):

Use Core Graphics to draw the text onto the `CGContext` in your `drawRect` method.  See the Drawing Text section of the [CGContext docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html)

Comment: i figured something like this would make more sense for memory management.